# How to install camel-http feature on Karaf

Tags: jbossfuse, fuseesb

I am using Fuse 7.7 on Apache Karaf.

I am getting this error

2020-09-28 18:08:57,689 | ERROR | lueprint Extender: 2 | o.a.a.b.c.BlueprintContainerImpl | 51 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.10.2 |
Unable to start container for blueprint bundle com.esb.iis-to-rm-vr/1.0.0 due to unresolved dependencies [(&(component=http)(objectClass=org.apache.camel.spi.ComponentResolver))]
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null

I did the below steps. camel-http is not installed.

**karaf@root()> features:install camel-http**

karaf@root()> features:list | grep camel-http

camel-http4

karaf@root()> list | grep camel-http

67 | Active  |  50 | 2.21.0.fuse-770013-redhat-00001 | camel-http-common

255 | Active  |  50 | 2.21.0.fuse-770013-redhat-00001 | camel-http4

Please let me know apart from the below step, what are the steps i need to follow to install camel-http.

karaf@root()> features:install camel-http

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful that `camel-http` is only meant to be a producer. You won't be able to do `from("http://...")` only with him. To be able to do it, you need to add a camel component that will allow your route to bind itself to the karaf's jetty. You can try to install `camel-jetty`.

Moreover, you're `feature:list | grep camel-http` seemed to have only returned `camel-http4`. I'm note sure `camel-http` feature has been dropped, but you could always install http4 component

Comment: I used features:install camel-http4 and used http4 in the route.  It is working as expected.